# Need to connect to the internet from private Virtual Machine on the cloud through a local server with internet access

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, 18.04

I have root access to a virtual machine on the cloud and a local server running Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 14 respectively. The virtual machine is connected to the local server with a private network. Since the Virtual machine is on a private network, it has no access to the internet. I would like to install tools and perform updates on the Virtual machine which would require an internet access.I have tried configuring port forwarding from the local server to the virtual machine, adding the private network as default in the virtual machine. Pinging a web address gives me the following error

> ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

Would he issue be because of the different version of Ubuntu on the servers? Is this the right way to approach the problem? Could it be done in any other way. The virtual machine in question doesn't have access to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever has the same problem. All you need to do is to change the NAT rules in /etc/ufw/before.rules add the following line

> *nat
>
> -A POSTROUTING -s /*IP address here*/ -o em1 -j MASQUERADE
>
> COMMIT

this has to be added to the local server trying to connect to the cloud and you have to change the DNS lookup in the virtual machine to 8.8.8.8, this allows the private virtual cloud to access the internet through the local server. Security settings of your local server serves as the firewall.